# In Woocommerce - How to show variation attribute in lower case same like set it in Product entry?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Looking solution for show product variation attribute in lowercase instead of capitalize ( same like i set in backend entry )

See 
1 - Backend entry http://prntscr.com/gny2f7

2 - Hows it getting display on cart page http://prntscr.com/gny32h

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine this isn't so much a woocommerce issue - more a theme issue. It looks to me like there's probably a CSS rule onthe cart items like:

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

From the front-end, try inspecting the element to see what rules are being applied.

Comment: i checked with Wordpress default theme Twenty fifteen and other. also text-transform: capitalize;  not work as i want variation attribute show in lowercase ( same like it set in backend entry )